# Visibility of triangle above camera?

Tags: camera, visibility

Is there a way to turn off visibility of the large triangle above the camera but retain the wireframe of the field of view (so the scene would appear like the example in the image on the right)? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to only disable the camera orientation arrow, however, you can remove both the arrow and the field of view by un-checking the box under under `Overlays > Extras`, or by just disabling overlays altogether:

[image: Camera]